# What is a spatial modeling approach that works with complex survey design, where multiple observations share single point location

Tags: regression, spatial

I'm working with the Demographic and Health Surveys data, which is a nationally representative household survey that uses a complex, two-stage cluster sampling design. In essence, this means that first, primary sampling units (like a community or census area) are selected with probability proportional to population size. Second, a set number of households (Ultimate Sampling Units) are randomly or systematically selected within that cluster for survey. Sampling weights are also created based on the actual number of counted households in a selected primary sampling unit.

One of the steps taken to preserve anonymity is that while GPS points are taken, they are only taken at the center of the Primary Sampling Unit, not for each household. There are other anonymization procedures in place for location, but that's beyond the scope of my current question.

I'd like to, for example, model the probability of facility-based delivery in a regression model that takes individual characteristics (i.e. antenatal care visits) and space & place into account.

The problem for all the modeling approaches (like CarBayes) I've encountered is that they assume each observation has its own location. I have one location for ~30 observaions, though I have locations across the entire country. I know I need some kind of hierarchical approach - I just can't figure out how to do this when the location would be at the "second" level of the model.

Several of the approaches I've seen in the literature deal with this by treating the cluster as the analysis unit and taking the 'count' of an indicator as the model outcome. However, this does not work if I also want to consider individual level characteristics.

I use R. Any help would be appreciated! Really, just looking for a modeling approach name that I can read up on and teach myself.